# ¿Cómo puedo hacer que una sentencia en mysql liste el nombre de las columnas de una determinada tabla?

Tags: mysql

tengo una tabla y quiero hacer una consulta para listar las columnas que coincidan con una determinada palabra

```sql
 select * from tabla.name where name.column like '%column_name%'
```

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con esto:

Solo reemplaza por el nombre de tu `base de datos`, nombre de tu `tabla` y el nombre de la columna que quieres buscar en esa `tabla`.

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME,COLUMN_TYPE,TABLE_NAME,DATA_TYPE 
FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`COLUMNS` 
WHERE 
TABLE_SCHEMA = 'tu_base_de_datos' 
AND TABLE_NAME = "tu_tabla" 
AND COLUMN_NAME LIKE "%nombre_columna%";
```

Comment: me resultó, como haria para poder obtener datos de la tabla que busque

Answer (score 0):

Para listar las columnas la consulta sería:

```
show columns from [tabla] like "%[palabra]%"
```

Esto te muestra información de cada columna en la tabla.

Comment: me resultó, como haria para poder obtener datos de la tabla que busque